# How to Mock a proxy connection in HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, httpclient

I am trying to Mock the below code but unsuccessful, Can anyone suggest how this can be achieved.

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                            .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                                    .proxy(proxy -> proxy
                                            .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                                            .host(host)
                                            .port(Integer.parseInt(port))));
    
ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
                    webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(clientHttpConnector).build();
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://gist.github.com/northernbird/0576c43968454f71622bfd3674a623cf

Comment: The code doesnt show how to mock the above mentioned code. But Thank you anyways @z atef

Comment: HttpEntity mockHttpEntity = mock(HttpEntity.class);
        when(mockHttpEntity.getContent()).thenReturn(SomeExpectedContent);

Answer (score 1):

Move the code which creates the `HttpClient` to it's own class:

```
interface HttpClientFactory {
   HttpClient create();
}

class DefaultHttpClientFactory implements HttpClientFactory {
   HttpClient create() {
      return HttpClient.create()
                            .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpCl...
   }
}
```

Now you can mock `HttpClientFactory` and the mock `HttpClient` it returns.